# How to add JSON Array name in JSON

Tags: php, json

I am new in PHP and just trying to encode mysql table's data into JSON format, and to get that i am using below script:

```
<?php
    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("mydatabase");
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE 1  ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
    $resultArray = array();
    while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
    {
        $arrCol = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
        {
            $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
        }
        array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
    }

    mysql_close($objConnect);

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
?>
```

and getting result in below format:

```
    [
    {
      "MemberID":"1",
      "Name":"Weerachai"
    },
    {
      "MemberID":"2",
      "Name":"Win"
    }
]
```

But what if i want to get response like this:

```
{
  "members": [ // i want to add this array
    {
      "MemberID":"1",
      "Name":"Weerachai"
    },
    {
      "MemberID":"2",
      "Name":"Win"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an array like the one you want and encode that.

```
echo json_encode(array('members' => $resultArray));
```

Comment: sorry thank you i made a stupid mistake, i ticked your answer as useful and will accept after two minutes